# instagram_graph_user_media, Sorry, Something went wrong

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

Im trying to use Facebook login.
My app is configured with on facebook with:

- The right package name
- The right hash key

My app has:

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">4444</string>
<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb4444</string>
<string name="facebook_client_token">4444secret</string>
```

When trying to get the "email" permissions everything works fine, but when trying to get the **instagram_graph_user_profile** im getting this error:

> sorry, Something went wrong.
> we are working on it and....

Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved this? i am also facing this

Comment: Hey, I think this api is not working, switched to instagram api directly (which is even more complicated, but it works)